# Render jquery versus include script MVC

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Scripts are generally added in the form header section of the html file:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

MVC .NET framework, by default it uses them at the bottom, after the footer the following way:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

**Question:**
I inspected the DOM and they are added. Using render at the bottom of layout, *does not* makes jQuery functionality like .affix work. But if I include the *same* two scripts at the top of the View, it works.
Example:

```
DOM (NOT Work):

<body data-target="#mysidebar" data-spy="scroll">
   <section>
    <div class="container">    
       <div id="mysidebar" class="col-md-3">
       ... Sidebar content
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-9">
       ... Content
       </div>
   </section>
</body>
<footer></footer>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


DOM (Works):

<body data-target="#mysidebar" data-spy="scroll">
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> <-- Added them here too make it work!
   <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <section>
    <div class="container">    
       <div id="mysidebar" class="col-md-3">
       ... Sidebar content
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-9">
       ... Content
       </div>
   </section>
</body>
<footer></footer>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Solution**

```
After trying many things this worked:
<body data-target="#mysidebar" data-spy="scroll">
   <section>
    <div class="container">    
       <div id="mysidebar" class="col-md-3">
       ... Sidebar content
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-9">
       ... Content
       </div>
   </section>
</body>
<footer></footer>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/classie.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/site.js"></script> <-- updated queries
```

Comment: is your script references are on a partial page?

Comment: Have you seen console log? Remember that usually jQuery loaded first before other scripts that requires it by placing inside `<head>` tag.

Comment: putting them at the bottom lets content load faster

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to have the scritps at the bottom of the page to reduce the time needed to load the page, unless if your script was needed at the top of the page, for ex: Modernizer

The reason why does it work if you included the script tag directly is most probably you forgot to add it in the BundleConfig, check the BunddleConfig and make sure the JQuery is included with the correct version, maybe it was included with a specific version which has been changed when you updated the package

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
```

Comment: No, they are added correctly. I am still unsure why I needed to added a second time see added code.

Comment: Did you check the generated HTML by viewing the source and make sure the the correct <script/> tags are added to the page? also are you referencing any of these libraries before they are added to the page?

Comment: Yes, that is what is crazy about. I moved all the Render scripts to be loaded in the <head> instead, (that shall be alright and fix problem right) well it does not. If I still add those two again to the View before the section part it works.

Comment: Can you inspect the network in the network tab when you open dev toolbar? just to find if thee is any file with 404

Comment: Narrowed it down it was some kind dependency order (not sure why).
In the header: added the jquery, bootstrap and my own script (site.js). Then after the footer added the additional ones like jquery validation and that seem to solve the problem. See my updated code above for details.